# NGINX reverse proxy to Apache/Nextcloud

Tags: apache, nginx, ssl, reverse-proxy, nextcloud

I have a Proxmox server with a NGINX server. As VPS I have a Nextcloud. I can login via IP.

My Proxmox is avaible via a Domain. I want the Nginx as reverse Proxy to my cloud and other services. I have this code in proxmox.conf

```html
upstream proxmox {
    server proxmox.domain.com;
    
}
 
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 permanent;
}
 
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name proxmox.domain.com;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ca-certificates/crt.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ca-certificates/key.key;
    proxy_redirect off;
    location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade"; 
        proxy_pass https://localhost:8006;
    proxy_buffering off;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    proxy_connect_timeout  3600s;
        proxy_read_timeout  3600s;
        proxy_send_timeout  3600s;
        send_timeout  3600s;
    }
}

upstream php {
    server nextcloud.domain.com;
}
server {

    listen 443;
    server_name nextcloud.domain.com;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ca-certificates/crt.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ca-certificates/key.key;
    proxy_redirect off;
    location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade"; 
        proxy_pass https://192.168.178.139:443;
    proxy_buffering off;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    proxy_connect_timeout  3600s;
        proxy_read_timeout  3600s;
        proxy_send_timeout  3600s;
        send_timeout  3600s;
    }
}
```

Here are the Ports of the Apache

```html
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>


NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080
Listen 127.0.0.1:8080

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Here ist the nextcloud.conf of the Apache:

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/nextcloud"
 ServerName nextcloud.domain.com

Redirect permanent / https://nextcloud.domain.com
Alias nextcloud.domain.com /var/www/html/nextcloud
 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

<Directory /var/www/nextcloud/>
 Options +FollowSymlinks
 AllowOverride All

 <IfModule mod_dav.c>
 Dav off
 </IfModule>

 SetEnv HOME /var/www/htm/nextcloud
 SetEnv HTTP_HOME /var/www/html/nextcloud
 Satisfy Any

</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I have change the Ports to 80/443 and I get everytime Bad Gateway 502

Here is the error Log of the Nginx server. The errorlog if Apache is empty.

```html
2021/04/10 14:41:47 [error] 2684#2684: *197 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 91.184.168.251, server: nextcloud.domain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://192.168.178.139:443/", host: "nextcloud.domain.com"
```

What I is wrong with this configuration? I tried a couple of options out of the Internet, but nothing works :/

I think the Apache refused it for security reason. But I don't know where I can config this, to get the Server run behind the reverse Proxy.

Can anybody help me? :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured trusted proxies?

> For security, you must explicitly define the proxy servers that Nextcloud is to trust. Connections from trusted proxies will be specially treated to get the real client information, for use in access control and logging. Parameters are configured in `config/config.php`

### Reference:

https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/21/admin_manual/configuration_server/reverse_proxy_configuration.html?highlight=trusted%20proxy#defining-trusted-proxies